my question is how to implement the procedural function in postgres
i am using a java spring boot as a backend and database as postgers so now my question is how to implement the procedural function in postgres like first i am writing the function in a seperate schema methods_query inside  in triggerFunction i am creating a new triggerFunction and in code i am writing this query
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION method_query.fn_user_info(
    fn_name CHAR,
    fn_gender CHAR,
    fn_state CHAR,
    fn_district CHAR,
    fn_email VARCHAR,
    fn_edit_id BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    fn_del_id BIGINT DEFAULT 0
)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    IF fn_del_id > 0 THEN
        DELETE FROM method_query.user_info WHERE id = fn_del_id;
    ELSIF fn_edit_id > 0 THEN
        UPDATE method_query.user_info SET
            name = fn_name,
            gender = fn_gender,
            state = fn_state,
            district = fn_district,
            email = fn_email
        WHERE id = fn_edit_id;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO method_query.user_info(name, gender, state, district, email)
        VALUES (fn_name, fn_gender, fn_state, fn_district, fn_email);
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


but this shows a syntax error like syntax error at or near "CREATE" LINE 5: AS $BODY$CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION method_query.fn_user_info
i trying to implement a crud opration using procdural function for example if i select the submit button the edit_id = null , delete_id = null if i select the update edit_id = 'has the specific id' , delete_id = null if i select the delete button the delete_id = 'has some id' so when this hit the data base it will go through a set of if condition and then do the required process
and one more this all my tables are in public schema and i dont know which one to use in schema either Functions or Trigger Function

There is nothing wrong with this function. Must be something before "CREATE", some other line of "code".

This AS $BODY$CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION method_query.fn_user_info says something else is trying to wrap your function definition inside another function definition.

The error means the body inside the $BODY$ quotes is missing a BEGIN at the top. If you want a plain SQL (not PL/pgSQL) function that doesn't need [DECLARE..]BEGIN..[EXCEPTION..]END sections and only wraps an alias for the create or replace function statement, don't use language plgpsql and switch to language sql. Demo
